# Setting Up SSL - Initial steps

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to convert my sockets program over to SSL. I'm just laying out the initial setup, and have come upon some run-time errors that I don't know how to resolve. Note: there is a file called 'my_server.pem' in the same directory as the c file.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

```
#include <openssl/bio.h> // BIO objects for I/O
#include <openssl/ssl.h> // SSL and SSL_CTX for SSL connections
#include <openssl/err.h> // Error reporting

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // data structures for SSL
    BIO *bio;
    SSL *ssl;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    // initialize openSSL
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    // set up the SSL context
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

    if (ctx == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "context is null\n");

    // load the trust store
    if (! SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "my_server.pem", NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading trust store\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        return 0;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "made it\n");

    //...

    return 0;
}
```

These are the error messages:

```
140735285130080:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:169:fopen('my_server.pem','r')
140735285130080:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:bss_file.c:172:
140735285130080:error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib:by_file.c:274:
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it looks like it is unable to locate `my_server.pem` file. Even though it is in the same location of your C-code, it will be accessible to your program as it is by its name when it will be present in the working directory.

So, either move the file to working directory of the application or give a relative or absolute path to the file which points to this file.

To diagnose further, open your file with `fopen` in read mode and see the last error if it fails.

If your `fopen` is able to open the file, then there is some other problem.

Comment: Thanks. I can't use an absolute path or this will fail the minute is is used on a different machine. As for a relative path, I don't know how to give a relative path to the same directory.

Comment: Is your exe in the same folder as C file?

Comment: If not, then put your certificate file in the same location as of exe. And ensure that is a valid certificate file.

Comment: By 'certificate file' are you referring to my_server.pem? This is in the same folder as the .exe. Is there another file I need to add to this folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try provide full path instead of `"my_server.pem"` [example here](http://www.len.ro/work/openssl-example/).

Or alternatively, try put `null` instead of `"my_server.pem"` and put **path to the directory** instead of `null` [refernce here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur/gtpc2/cpp_ssl_ctx_load_verify_locations.html).